# WooCommerce - Add information to "thank you" page by function hooked in shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I have a custom shipping method and I want it to display its description (shipping instructions) on Thank you page and in email sent to customer. Just as payment gateways do. I am hooking to `woocommerce_thankyou` hook in my shipping method `init()` function. It works, but ... it works like eight times. Those hooked functions are firing multiple times. My shipping method looks like this:

```
<?php
class WC_Shipping_XY extends WC_Shipping_Method {

    function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
        
        $this->id = 'my-shipping';
        // etc etc
        
        $this->init();
    }
    

    function init() {

        $this->init_form_fields();
        // etc
        
        add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this, 'woocommerce_thankyou' ), 5, 1 ); 
    }
    
    
    function woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
        
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        
        if( $order->has_shipping_method('my-shipping') ) {
            
            echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->description ) );
            
        }
    }   
        
}
```

Shipping method description is duplicated many times on Thank you page. I don't know why. Is shipping method constructor called more than once? (Obviously it is ...)

Comment: What exactly is `$this->description` ? Because once you figure out how to get that outside of the class your problem is solved. You don't have to call `woocommerce_thankyou` inside your shipping class. @Marek

Comment: Yeah, that property (and more) is ommited in my class code example. The problem is I WANT to call that hook inside my shipping class :-) I don't want to maintain it on some other place (functions.php,...).

Comment: I think its a wrong place to add. If you could share the description's purpose, we could actually look at solutions on how it can be achieved.

Comment: It's just simple text with information for customer (I know it's more complicated with "shipping instances"). I just don't get why it's not possible to deal with it inside shipping method class. Where is the problem ...

Comment: Why are you extending shipping method to hook the `thank_you` page?  Just hook thank_you with your message.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it should be done.

- You create your custom shipping method.

```
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {

    function your_shipping_method_init()
    {
        if (!class_exists('WC_Your_Shipping_Method')) {
            class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method
            {

                public $description = null;


                /**
                 * Constructor for your shipping class
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct()
                {
                    $this->id                 = 'your_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                    $this->method_title       = __('Your Shipping Method');  // Title shown in admin
                    $this->method_description = __('Description of your shipping method'); // Description shown in admin

                    $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                    $this->title              = "My Shipping Method"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                    $this->description = __('Some other description'); // Description shown in admin

                    $this->init();
                }

                /**
                 * Init your settings
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                function init()
                {
                    // Load the settings API
                    $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                    $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                    // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                    add_action('woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
                }

                /**
                 * calculate_shipping function.
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @param mixed $package
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function calculate_shipping($package = array())
                {
                    $rate = array(
                        'label' => $this->title,
                        'cost' => '10.99',
                        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                    );

                    // Register the rate
                    $this->add_rate($rate);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action('woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init');

    function add_your_shipping_method($methods)
    {
        $methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method');
}
```

*Please see that it has a `description` class variable inside of it, which is different from `method_description` used by WooCommerce.*

- Use the thankyou hook outside your class like this to get that description.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou', 5, 1);


function woocommerce_thankyou($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if ($order->has_shipping_method('your_shipping_method')) {
        $shipping = new WC_Your_Shipping_Method();
        $description = $shipping->description;
        echo wpautop(wptexturize($description));
    }
}
```

I have tested this code and it works.

Screenshot below. You can see `Some other description` on the thank you page.

[image]

Comment: I don't thnk this solves my problem, and I don't think initializing `new WC_Your_Shipping_Method()`  in that thankyou hook is correct. After all, my shipping method supports instances, and any of them can have different description.

Comment: well if, the `description` is dynamic pls tell us how is it dynamic ? Also I am not sure you can gain access to that instance once the checkout is complete. There is one other way, which can you can use to make this work, its through using order meta to store the value, but you need to tell how is `description` dynamic to the user. @Marek

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found out this behaviour is "by design", someone asked the same question on WooCommerce Github ([issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/20548)).

*Shipping methods/instances are not singletons and can be init/loaded/constructed multiple times depending on whats going on.*

It's not possible to hook any function inside shipping method class - if so, it will result in multiple function calls. Period.